# How to change double click behavior of contacts in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

When double clicking on a name on the `To / CC` field in Outlook 2007, it used to open `Outlook Properties` of the contact.

But in Outlook 2013, it opens the `Contact Card`. To open Outlook Properties, one needs to right click on the name then select the option.

Is there a way to change the default double click operation to open Outlook Properties instead of Contact Card?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/use-outlooks-contacts-contact-cards/

Comment: Is there a way to get to open Outlook Properties dialog box instead of Contact Card in `Skype for Business 2015 [Formerly called as 'Lync 2015]`

Comment: I would like to know this as well, sukumar.  I have not found a way yet, but I feel like this is a step back in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Open a notepad and copy the following information:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\contactcard]
"TurnOnLegacyGALDialog"=dword:00000001
```

1. Save the file as Outlook.reg
2. Close Outlook and double click on the file. It will make changes in registry.
3. Open Outlook and check if the option has started working, if not then restart the machine.